# How i can concatenate parent value recursivily based on parentid with linq query or SQL

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

Suppose i have data like that

ID ParentID Title

1  Null    America

2  1       Texas

3  2       Dallas

i want result like that through LINQ/EF or SQL Queries

ID Title

1 America

2 America/Texas

3 America/Texas/Dallas

Comment: What's your question? You only say what you want, not where you're stuck.

Comment: actually i didnt stuck anywhere , i just need below query , i dont know about this query from start .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH H AS
(
    -- Anchor: the first level of the hierarchy
    SELECT id, ParentID, Title, CAST(Title AS NVARCHAR(300)) AS path 
    FROM TestTABLE 
    WHERE parentid IS NULL      
UNION ALL
    -- Recursive: join the original table to the anchor, and combine data from both  
    SELECT T.id, T.ParentID, T.Title, CAST(H.path + '\' + T.Title AS NVARCHAR(300)) 
    FROM TestTABLE T INNER JOIN H ON T.ParentID = H.id
)

SELECT * FROM H
```

Comment: perfect , if any one can do it with Linq